# unable to mount filesystem: not authorized

Tags: filesystem

I have two extra hard-drive. But I can't access to them. I got error msg: 
unable to mount filesystem: not authorized

Any advice? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try mounting using gparted parttion manager

to install gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

try posting output of

```
sudo fdisk -l
```